# Codeigniter db query on two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im new to codeigniter and php, mysql and i am making a codeigniter app, and have a question about db querys using active records.

I want to loop through the "users" table and at the same time get a table called cv where the userid is equal to owner_id in the cv records. The cv table has a lot of columns like school, start_date, end_date, grades etc. Heres how i did it:

The controller:

```
function index() {
    $data['members'] = $this->user_model->_search_members();
    $data['main_content'] = 'agency/start';
    $this->load->view('site_view', $data);
}
```

The model:

```
function _search_members()
{

    $this->db->select('id,username,first_name,last_name,company,presentation,title_1,title_2,title_3,last_login,user_pic,counties,municipalities,birthday,gender,webpage')->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}

function _get_cv($id) {
    $this->db->select()->where('owner_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('cv');

    return $query->result();
}
```

The view:

```
<section id="main">

<h2>Search members</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>School</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($members as $member) : ?>
        <?php $cvs = $this->user_model->_get_cv($member->id); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/users/thumbs/<?=$member->user_pic;?>" alt=""></td>
            <td><a href="profile/view/<?php echo $member->id; ?>"><?php echo $member->username;?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->gender;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->first_name; ?> <?php echo $member->last_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->title_1; ?> / <?php echo $member->title_2; ?> / <?php echo $member->title_3; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->counties; ?> i <?php echo $member->municipalities; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->birthday;?></td>
            <td>
                <?php foreach ($cvs as $cv) : ?>
                    <?php echo $cv->school; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Now my question is, is this a good way to do it? I also want to be able to search through the users and cv tables on the page with a form i am creating later. Should i do a join on the tables instead to able to make better search queries or can i still do it this way?

Any help appreciated.

Regards

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('cv', 'users.id = cv.owner_id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

For more information:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Updated:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('cv', 'users.id = cv.owner_id','left');
$data = $this->db->get();

$group_cv = $users = array();
foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
    $group_cv[$v['id']][] = $v;
}

foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
    $users[$v['id']] = $v;
}

?>

<section id="main">

<h2>Search members</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>School</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($users as $member) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/users/thumbs/<?=$member->user_pic;?>" alt=""></td>
            <td><a href="profile/view/<?php echo $member->id; ?>"><?php echo $member->username;?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->gender;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->first_name; ?> <?php echo $member->last_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->title_1; ?> / <?php echo $member->title_2; ?> / <?php echo $member->title_3; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->counties; ?> i <?php echo $member->municipalities; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member->birthday;?></td>
            <td>
                <?php foreach ($group_cv[$member['id']] as $cv) : ?>
                    <?php echo $cv->school; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the fast reply. But how do i loop through them so that i get all the info on one row in the html table. Say if a user got 5 schools in the cv database. I want them to show up in one td. Instead of getting 5 td with the username and all user info?

Comment: You should separate data from DB  into the `user group array`.<br>
Like this:

//here is your 
$group = array();
$data = data from DB

foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
  $group[$v['id']] = $v;
}

Comment: I cant get this to work. Its just me having a hard time to grasp this. I still get 5 rows with username. Could you post an example with this code? Would really appreciate it :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a bad way of doing it? Seems like the query takes a longer time to retrieve the data? `$data = $this->db->query('SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.username ,users.last_name,
 GROUP_CONCAT( cv.school ) AS schools,
 GROUP_CONCAT( cv.occupation ) AS occupation,
 GROUP_CONCAT( cv.instrument ) AS instrument,
 GROUP_CONCAT( cv.program ) AS program
 FROM users INNER JOIN cv ON users.id = cv.owner_id GROUP BY users.id');
?>` i know the query is not escaped. If i can do it this way, then how do i escape it? Or make us of active records?

Comment: It's not a good way.You should  use query with 'joins'.It's better to use GROUP_CONCAT for specific limited data.